# Change Pull To Refresh Activity Indicator

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, tableview, uirefreshcontrol

I have an `ActivityIndicator` on my `tableView` which appears when I pull to refresh.

I was wondering if I can change the color of the spinning indicator, here is my implimentation:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     refreshData()
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleRefresh(refreshControl:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)

}

func handleRefresh(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    self.refreshData()
    sleep(2)
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()

}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you refer this, http://www.appcoda.com/custom-pull-to-refresh/? @Alec.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply change the `tintColor` of `refreshControl`

```
self.refreshControl.tintColor = .red
```

Comment: @Alec. Welcome mate :)